# No way to get external IP

Tags: dynamic-ip

I've successfully tried all these methods (got from other posts/questions) to get internet IP in Ubuntu but...
curl ipecho.net
curl ifconfig.me
curl ipecho.net/plain
curl ipinfo.io/ip
Output:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -Command here (any of 4 before curls)-
**< html>< /html>** pi@raspberrypi:~ $  (in the same line)

curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
Output (html code):
var hardwarePlatform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
Etcetera

wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
Output:  nothing

wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
Ootput (html code):
< ! DOCTYPE html> 
< html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    < head>
< meta name="csrf_token" content="/gRClgpBjNDPhyORm0miqmAlQJfxVmiQ"/>
Etcetera

EDIT: First thing I think is if those outputs are not IP numbers there would be a problem with internet connection (not related with RPi - off topic as stated by some users). Sorry.

Comment: Please bring some structure into your text and sample outputs.

Comment: I thought I could clarify your question by editing it, but your formatting is all over the place, so I didn't. If you can actually make your question readable, then we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Even if you made this very clear (you are trying to get your external IP, i.e., the one used by your LAN router) and use impeccable formatting, this is off-topic here as it really has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.  You might try our larger sibling site, [Super User](http://superuser.com/), or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That´s something I don't know. It never happened to me until in RPi and it has gone after some reboots. It was strange to have an output "<html></html>" from those 4 curl command options

Comment: Now it comes again. After changing connection to another network, curl ipinfo.io/ip outputs <html></html>. After some reboots, DC reconnections, network changes I am getting the same output

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't completely clear, but you can use `hostname` to show only the IP address of you machine like so:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ hostname -I
151.101.193.69
```

"hostname -I" returns the local, LAN, IP address.

"curl https://api.ipify.org/"      returns the remote, WAN, IP address and nothing else. It's 15 of less characters. e.g. "16.218.186.74"

Comment: Sorry, I added in the post that it is the internet IP what I mean. 
 I get internal IP with ifconfig

Comment: I couldn't try your suggestion "curl https://api.ipify.org/" because I read it after problem gone and all methods are working fine now. Thanxs